# App Store Connect: Can I submit an earlier build to TestFlight than the latest one?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, appstore-approval

I had version 5.1.0 of my app on TestFlight, and then published version 4.1.0 to the Store (per client's request). I want to start pushing all builds to TestFlight before pushing them to the store, but I need to keep the versions in the 4 range. Am I able to push 4.1.1 or 4.2.0 to TestFlight even though I already have 5.1.0 on TestFlight already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App Store: If my last production release was v4.1.5 but last TestFlight was v5.2.0, can I release 4.1.10 to Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73777192/app-store-if-my-last-production-release-was-v4-1-5-but-last-testflight-was-v5-2)

Comment: No, sorry, what I meant is that I currently 5.1.0 on TestFlight, but then when I push 4.1.0 to TestFlight, if I open the TestFlight app on my phone it still shows 5.1.0, I assume because that's a later version than 4.1.0. Is there any way to get 4.1.0 to appear on the TestFlight app on my phone?

Comment: In TestFlight app you can see all TestFlight versions  with previous builds.